# Kofax Export Connector registration

Tags: c#, kofax

I want to create a Kofax Export Connector and register it in the Administration module. I created a `Class Library (.NET Framework)` with the following code for the setup and release

**KfxReleaseSetupScript.cs**

```
namespace Kofax_CoBRA_Export
{
    [Guid("b826cc5a-ed80-4fe1-a80f-86a08cca2851")]
    public interface IKfxReleaseSetupScript
    {
        ReleaseSetupData SetupData { get; set; }
        KfxReturnValue OpenScript();
        KfxReturnValue CloseScript();
        KfxReturnValue RunUI();
        KfxReturnValue ActionEvent(KfxActionValue action, string dataStringOne, string dataStringTwo);
    }

    [Guid("39a4f6f6-0de1-40b2-8934-d9a7c2c79468")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("Kofax_CoBRA_Export.KfxReleaseSetupScript")]
    internal class KfxReleaseSetupScript : IKfxReleaseSetupScript
    {
        // Interface Implementation
    }
}
```

**KfxReleaseScript.cs**

```
namespace Kofax_CoBRA_Export
{
    [Guid("091d8f6c-b4c4-42d4-81aa-3b86b31ce46d")]
    public interface IKfxReleaseScript
    {
        ReleaseData DocumentData { get; set; }
        KfxReturnValue OpenScript();
        KfxReturnValue CloseScript();
        KfxReturnValue ReleaseDoc();
    }

    [Guid("e034c243-ae35-4823-9f2f-10bb6a6fe5c0")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("Kofax_CoBRA_Export.ReleaseScript")]
    internal class KfxReleaseScript : IKfxReleaseScript
    {
        // Interface Implementation
    }
}
```

My `.inf` registration file contains this code

```
[Scripts]
Kofax_CoBRA_Export
[Kofax_CoBRA_Export]
SetupModule=.\bin\Debug\Kofax_CoBRA_Export.dll
SetupProgID=Kofax_CoBRA_Export.KfxReleaseSetupScript
SetupVersion=1.0
ReleaseModule=.\bin\Debug\Kofax_CoBRA_Export.dll
ReleaseProgID=Kofax_CoBRA_Export.KfxReleaseScript
ReleaseVersion=1.0
SupportsNonImageFiles=True
RemainLoaded=True
SupportsKofaxPDF=True
SupportsOriginalFileName=True
SupportsMultipleInstances=False
DisplayName=Kofax_CoBRA_Export
```

When I select the `.inf` file in the adminstration module I just get an empty box so there is nothing to install.

I took the information from

> Kofax Capture Developer's Guide 10.0.0
>
> KCEC-Text Exporter Sample
>
> Kofax Capture API Reference Guide
>
> Kofax Capture Export Type Library

but I really don't get why I get anything to install in the administration module. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When providing a relative path, Kofax expects the binaries in its own directory (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Kofax\CaptureSS\ServLib\Bin` on a server, as admin.exe runs using this working path). In your case that would translate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Kofax\CaptureSS\ServLib\Bin\bin\Debug\Kofax_CoBRA_Export.dll`.

Note that Kofax recommends copying all custom binaries including your inf file to the server directory, however I prefer creating a sub folders for my code, putting all files there. Then, my inf file would look as follows:

```
[Scripts]
SmartCAP.KEC.EnergieAG.SAP

[SmartCAP.KEC.EnergieAG.SAP]
SetupModule=SmartCAP.KEC.EnergieAG.SAP.dll
SetupProgID=SmartCAP.KEC.EnergieAG.SAP.Setup
SetupVersion=11.0
ReleaseModule=SmartCAP.KEC.EnergieAG.SAP.dll
ReleaseProgID=SmartCAP.KEC.EnergieAG.SAP
ReleaseVersion=11.0
SupportsNonImageFiles=True
SupportsKofaxPDF=True
```

Note that Kofax still needs to be able to resolve all dependencies you used in your solution - most definitely internal ones such as the `Kofax.ReleaseLib.Interop.DLL` - so, you could either copy them there, or - that's what I'd prefer, use a custom assembly resolver in your code, pointing to the server directory.

Comment: well now I can try to install the export connector but I get the error `invalid ProgId` 
 again ..

Comment: If this answer solved your particular issue, please consider marking it as the accepted answer in addition to upvoting it - thanks. Regarding the invalid ProgId message: please check out this article. If the issue cannot be resolved, please feel free to ask another question any time. http://knowledgebase.kofax.com/faqsearch/results.aspx?QAID=3379